# django how to get request object (url param) in class based view

Tags: python, django

I have a class based view which has a query set like below:

```
def get_queryset(self):  
        queryset = Article.objects.all()
        return queryset
```

If I pass an article id as a URL parameter like this:
`<url>/stories/?articleid=1000`

Then how can I get this value in the get_queryset function so that I can use it to filter? something like below:

```
def get_queryset(self):  
        articleId = #get the article_id from URL. How to do this?
        queryset = Article.objects.filter(article_id=articleId)
        return queryset
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you can get it from `self.request.GET["articleid']`.

Note however this is not best practice in Django; you should write a URL pattern that includes the id directly, so that your URL would be `/stories/100/`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason why I need it like this is because I have to filter articles based on author as well. I already have a url like `articles/100` which actually maps to the articlesDetailView. I am trying this pattern for articlesListView filter... does that make sense? I am very new to Django.

Comment: @UndefinedVariable It's better to retrieve `articleid` that way `self.request.GET.get("articleid')` so in case the `articleid` doesn't exist in the URL, you will not get `keyerror`